# JS socket.io function undefined in onMessage handler

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I got a socket.io client in which the `onMessage` callback should call `handleResponse()` to process the received data.

I attached the callback like this:

```
this.socket.on("message", this._socketOnMessage);
```

The callback is implemented like this:

```
_socketOnMessage(data) {
    this.handleResponse();
}
```

And this is `handleResponse()`

```
handleResponse() {
    console.log("handling response");
}
```

I can call `handleResponse()` from anywhere and it works fine, but when called trom the socket callback I get this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.handleResponse is not a function
```

`handleResponse()` is `undefined` in the callback but `function` everywhere else

Why do I get this error and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution is simple:

The scope inside the `_socketOnMessage` function is `WebSockets`.
Subsequently `this` refers to the `WebSocket` object and not my parent Class in which the socket lives.

So to call `handleResponse` which also is a function of the parent class it has to be called like this:

`parentObject.handleResponse()`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like `handleResponse` isn't a function of your socket manager. Just call `handleResponse()` instead of `this.handleResponse()`.

Comment: the scope in the onMessage Handler is "WebSocket" so I think you're right, however just calling handleResponse gives me an "not defined" compilation error

Comment: Glad you worked it out! Next time on SO, it's helpful to provide a broader image of your code to get a better answer. From what I was given, handleResponse did not have a visible parent object.